# Firing Typeahead on focus

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

The default Typeahead behaviour is to return matches on the change event, I think.

Is it simple to return matches on the focus event as well? That is, all values should match an empty string?

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
text$
  .debounceTime(200)
  .map(term => this.lists.filter(v => new RegExp(term, 'gi').test(v.title)).slice(0, 10));
```

The above code will return all values when the input changes to an empty string,

This is the result I desire, except on focus.

[image]

Comment: This is not currently supported but is planned, see: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/698

Comment: Good news. Thanks for responding